# Encountering 'Gradle Duplicate class found' error after adding dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I'm looking to implement in-app updates and am following the guidance provided by Google

https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/in-app-updates/kotlin-java#kts

As such i'm trying to add the following dependencies

```
implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.0")
implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.0.0")
```

However when trying to build the project I am confronted with a Duplicate class found error. One example provided below, although there are many of these

```
com.google.android.play.core.appupdate.AppUpdateInfo found in modules jetified-app-update-2.0.0-runtime (com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.0) and jetified-core-1.10.2-runtime (com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2)
```

I tried to work. around this by adding some exclude clauses in configurations

```
configurations {
    all {
        exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "app-update"
        exclude group: "com.google.android.play", module: "core"
    }
}
```

The example above is the one that finally allowed the program to build, however when I go to utilise the library it is clear many of its elements have not been imported correctly. When I try to instantiate the AppUpdateManager, it is missing and AppUpdateResult seems to be the only one available to use.

[image]

Would really appreciate some guidance on what I may be doing wring here and any fixes or workarounds

Answer (score 8):

use this

```
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.9.0'
```

and remove both

```
implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update:2.0.0")
implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.0.0")
```

Comment: You're right that he shouldn't add both `app-update` and `app-update-ktx` dependencies but `core` is deprecated and shouldn't be used anymore as the library was broken up. If you're currently using `core` in your project you can follow this doc to migrate: https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem. In short, I was using `com.google.android.play:core-ktx` and wanted to migrate to "multiple per-feature libraries" (https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore#playcore-migration). But I kept getting "duplicate com.google.android.play:core" error message, even though I already removed it.

It turned out that one of the libraries I was using (`androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.5.0-alpha03`, to be specific) was including `com.google.android.play:core:1.10.2` behind the scene. When I updated to `androidx.navigation:navigation-dynamic-features-fragment:2.6.0-alpha08`, the problem went away, and I was able to migrate to Google Play Core's per-feature libraries.

Comment: how did you find that behind the scene ? :D

Comment: When you run "./gradlew :app:dependencies --configuration debugRuntimeClasspath" from terminal, it shows a graph of which package depends what.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in adding a dependency twice, only to exclude it from the build.
Only add `implementation("com.google.android.play:app-update-ktx:2.0.0")`.

Comment: I tried adding only one or the other, without any exclusions, and i'm still getting the duplicate class error. I'm especially mystified as to what 'jetified' is that is appearing in the error message that my libraries appear to be duplicating

Comment: @Murphler the jetifier tool migrates support-library-dependent libraries to rely on the equivalent AndroidX packages. This likely defined in your gradle.properties "android.enableJetifier=true". Nevertheless removing this will still cause the same problem but wont include jetifier in the error :(

Answer (score 0):

As of 19/12/23 The in-app update feature works even  without the dependencies .
So please remove the dependencies and try once again...